# upgrading firebase from 2.x to 3.x (objective c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Databasics.m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lu1eH.png)

[Databasics.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dReFz.png)

I need to upgrade an objective-c based program from firebase 2.x to 3.x sdk. However, I meet some problems as you can see. I changed to the new reference style and corresponding declarations and new class names, but there is an error: use of undeclared identifier 'dataBasicsInstance'. Actually others functions are also have the same errors. I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `init` method is missing a closing `}` for the `if(self = [super init]) {` before the `return self;` line

Because of this the compiler thinks that `dataBasicsInstance` is still part of the `init` method instead of a new method.